# Regular expression in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where the string from a column has a value "/Date(-34905600000)/". The value within brackets could be in any one of the following patters

1. "/Date(-34905600000)/"
2. "/Date(1407283200000)/"
3. "/Date(1636654411000+0000)/"

I need to extract all inside the parenthesis for examples 1 and 2 including the "-" if any. For the 3rd example, it should be only the numbers inside the parenthesis before "+" ie 1636654411000.

I tried the following and not getting the results as the output is coming along with the parenthesis.

```
select REGEXP_substr("/Date(-34905600000)/", '\\([[:alnum:]\-]+\\)') 
from table A;

select REGEXP_substr("/Date(-34905600000)/", '\\((.*?)\\)') from table 
A;

select REGEXP_substr("/Date(-34905600000)/", '[0-9]+') from table A;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexp_replace()` instead you could do:

```
 regexp_replace(colA, '(\\/Date\\()([-0-9]*)(.*)', '\\2')
```

That splits the string into three substitution groups and then only keeps the second. I often end up doing `regexp_replace()` with substitution groups like this when `regexp_substr()` fails me.

Comment: That worked perfect too. Thank you!. I have solutions to use both regexp_replace() and REGEXP_substr()

Answer (score 2):

if you want the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) to sub-matches you need to use the `'e'` <regex_parameters> option, and then you can use 1 as the  to match your first grouping, thus:

```
SELECT column1,
    REGEXP_substr(column1, 'Date\\(([-+]?[0-9]+)',1,1,'e')
FROM VALUES
  ('"/Date(-34905600000)/"'),
  ('"/Date(1407283200000)/"'),
  ('"/Date(1636654411000+0000)/"');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 'DATE\(([-+]?[0-9]+)',1,1,'E') |
| --- | --- |
| "/Date(-34905600000)/" | -34905600000 |
| "/Date(1407283200000)/" | 1407283200000 |
| "/Date(1636654411000+0000)/" | 1636654411000 |

I am quite sure the regexp is greedy by default, but otherwise you can force the match to the timezone or paren with

```
'Date\\(([-+]?[0-9]+)[-+\\)]'
```